# confused on how to call on method inside class

Tags: java

So I need to get input from a user, which I have done, but then I need it to print out the giveFirstClassStamps amount and givePennyStamps amount, and I am at a loss as how to do this.
Any help or pointers in the right directions would be greatly appreciated.

```
import java.util.*;
/**
*/
public class StampMachine
{
public static final int FIRST_CLASS_STAMP_PRICE = 44;
private int balance;

/**
  Constructs a stamp machine with a zero balance.
*/
     public StampMachine() 
{ 
   balance = 0; 
}

public static void main( String[ ]  args)
{
       Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

      System.out.print("Enter 16-Digit Credit Card Number: ");
      String cardNumber = input.nextLine();
      System.out.print("Enter Month/Year of Expiration Date in MM/YY format: ");
      String expirationDate = input.nextLine();
      System.out.print("Stamp Purchase Amount: ");
      int dollars = input.nextInt();


}

/**
   Adds a given number of dollar bills into this machine.
   @param dollars the number of dollar bills
*/
public void insert(int dollars)
{  
    balance = balance + 100 * dollars;
}

/**
   Dispenses first class stamps for the inserted payment.
   @return the number of first class stamps
*/
public int giveFirstClassStamps()
{
   int firstClassStamps = balance / FIRST_CLASS_STAMP_PRICE;
   balance = balance - firstClassStamps * FIRST_CLASS_STAMP_PRICE;
   return firstClassStamps;
}

/**
   Dispenses penny stamps for the inserted payment.
   @return the number of penny stamps
*/
public int givePennyStamps()
{
  int pennyStamps = balance;
   balance = 0;
   return pennyStamps;      
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an instance of the class and then call the methods. Try the following after getting your input variables:

```
StampMachine sm = new StampMachine();
sm.insert(dollars);
```

You can continue using that same instance "sm" to call other methods as well.

Answer (score 0):

In main, after getting the `dollars`

```
call insert method. Modify method sigantures to pass dollars entered by the user
call giveFirstClassStamps and assign the returned value to a local variable inside main
do the same for givePennyStamps and now print the values
```

Hope this helps.